# Date comparison with comparison operators

Tags: php, date, comparison, string-comparison, date-comparison

i have a php code where i am trying to compare dates and the condition is if the currentdate is <= frmdate then query rows has to be inserted in array whereas the problem now happening is that it inserts only rows which are less than and not which is equalsto currentdate... please help me in resolving this issue

```
$prodarray= array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $todateExtracted=$row['to_date'];
    $fromdateExtracted=$row['from_date'];
    $toDate=strtotime($todateExtracted);
    $frmDate=strtotime($fromdateExtracted);

    if($currentdate <= $frmDate)
    {
       $prodarray[] = $row;
    } 
    // $i++;
}
```

Comment: What format is the dates? If it's anything else than UNIX, that is your problem. So if it's date() it's a string. You can't compare strings. Sorry my bad. Didn't read carefully enough. Wait... What is $currentdate?

Comment: HOW and WHAT do you load into `$currentdate`

Comment: My bet it's a string value of today. Since rest of the code looks ok, a bit clumsy but ok. And the question is tagged "string comparison". Wanna bet against me @Riggs :-)

Comment: @Andreas No, but what are the odd on `19/07/2017` and what are the odds on `19-07-2017` ?? and what do I get for `mm-dd-YYYY`

Comment: @Riggs ohh. That's a tough one... He is in India. So I bet he uses American way of writing. So I believe you are correct with mm-dd-YYYY. Or maybe it's only YY...

Answer (score 0):

Use `Strtotime()`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
$prodarray= array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $todateExtracted=$row['to_date'];
    $fromdateExtracted=$row['from_date'];
    $toDate=strtotime($todateExtracted);
    $frmDate=strtotime($fromdateExtracted);
    if(strtotime($currentdate) <= strtotime($frmDate))
    {
       $prodarray[] = $row;
    } 
   // $i++;
}
```

Comment: A little dangerous if you dont know the format used for the date in `$currentdate`

Comment: Well, @RiggsFolly OP did not provide the date format. However, in most 'normal' cases, `strtotime()` should work.